# Query MySQL em node ignorando condição de diferença

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, select

Tenho tido um problema peculiar enquanto alterando meu servidor Node.JS para determinadas queries de MySQL. Eu tenho o seguinte código que funciona normalmente no MySQL Workbench:

```
SELECT id, nome FROM `tabela` WHERE categoria <> 2;
```

Mas no node-mysql a query continua a selecionar linhas com categoria igual a 2, e apesar de rescrever o código por diversas vezes e tentar outras formas de obter o resultado, incluindo tratamento no lado cliente (por selecionar a categoria e fazer um `if(objeto.categoria !=2)`). Não funciona.

Isso se trata de um *bug*? Ou pode ser algo no meu código que não estou percebendo?

Os trechos de código onde faço a seleção, de forma mais detalhada, estão disponíveis abaixo:

```
// Evento para requisição WebSocket - Lado Server
socket.on('req-table-list', function(){
     db.query("SELECT id, nome FROM `banco_de_dados`.`tabela` WHERE categoria <> 2", function(err, rows){
         if(err){
             socket.emit('res-table-list', {content: null, error: err.code});
         }
         else{
             socket.emit('res-table-list', {content: rows, error: null});
         }
     });
});

// Evento para resposta WebSocket - Lado Client

socket.on('res-table-list', function(data){
    for(var i=0; i<data.content.length; i++){
        $("#myDiv").append(data.content[i].nome + '-' + data.content[i].id)
    }
});
```

Comment: ja tentou fazer da forma que nosso colega colocou na resposta  dessa pergunta [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244799/timing-issue-with-mysql-query-in-nodejs), no lugar do valor fixo passaria ?, depois passaria os valores em um array como segundo parametro no método query

Comment: Tentei e ainda sim o SELECT está retornando linhas com categoria = 2

Comment: Experimenta trocar o condicional `<>` por `!=`